# CPU Core and thread relation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, cpu

I am trying to understand threads and their behavior.

My basic operating system understanding is the possible number of threads in running state is

```
CPU CORES * THREADS.
```

Like my system has an i5 processor which has 2 cores and 4 threads, so at max 8 threads can run at a time.

To validate my understanding I created a 10 simple continues running program

```
public class A1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0;;){
            System.out.println("Blocking forever");
        }
    }
}
```

But I was able to run 10 blocking programs at the same time. Why I was able to run more blocking threads than capacity.

Also, While running I tried to check threads count in `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()`, but it was having the only reference to one main, but A1 main is different from A2 main in the program running independently

```
Id =1 | Name =main | state==RUNNABLE
```

What I am missing to understand

Comment: Modern operating systems are all pre-emptively multi-tasking. Each thread in Java is isomorphic to a native thread (e.g. the operating system scheduler schedules the threads just like it does all of the running threads on your computer). The operating system gives each thread some time to run, and then pre-empts the thread; allowing another to run. Hundreds of threads can be running on a typical computer. From `top` on my machine: `Processes: 391 total, 3 running, 388 sleeping, 1853 threads`

Comment: "Like my system has an i5 processor which has 2 cores and 4 threads, so at max 8 threads can run at a time." - you should distinguish between _hardware_ threads (i.e. cores supporting multiple parallel threads) and _software_ threads (i.e. processes, applications, etc.) - so 2 cores * 4 hardware threads per core means up to 8 software threads can run concurrently .. and a lot more could be waiting for their slot to run (and due to OS scheduling they'll normally run eventually).

Comment: so java JVM is running as one thread and it internally can have many threads which do context switching and manages its thread time.

Comment: *so java JVM is running as one thread and it internally can have many threads which do context switching and manages its thread time* The Java threads are all native threads. JVM has multiple threads (at least the garbage collector and main thread), but they are **native** threads.

Comment: Are all threads user creates even its continuous blocks, the os will always allocate time and schedule based on context switching @ElliottFrisch

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/javadump_tags_javaandnative_thread_detail.html